# Can't find variable: direction

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Stuck with this problem, probably some logic mistake, but can't find it by myself
Any correction to this? (problem - 'Can't find variable: direction'. Using react.

```
const GameScreen = props => {
const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState(
    generateRandomBetween(1, 100, props.userChoice)
);
    const currentLow = useRef(1);
    const currentHigh = useRef(100);

    const nextGuessHandler = direction => {
        if ((direction === 'lower' && currentGuess < props.userChoice) || (direction === 'greater' && currentGuess > props.userChoice))
        Alert.alert('Don\'t lie!', 'You know that this is wrong...', [{text: 'Sorry!', style: 'cancel'}
    ]);
    return;
    }
    if (direction === 'lower') {
        currentHigh.current = currentGuess;
    } else {
        currentLow.current = currentGuess;
    }
    const nextNumber = generateRandomBetween(currentLow.current, currentHigh.current, currentGuess);
    setCurrentGuess(nextNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `direction` is only defined inside the function `nextGuessHandler`, so it fails when trying to use it outside the function